# The middleware in Redux Typescript has problem when trying to create new store

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userAPI } from "./api/userAPI";

export const server = import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER;

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [userAPI.reducerPath]: userAPI.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (mid) => [ <---
        ...mid(),
        userAPI.middleware
    ]
});
```

There is an error message when I try to use Typescript to create new redux store with the middleware. I do not understand why the `middleware` is highlighted in red even though it is in correct format. Can anyone help or explain the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Redux Toolkit, you need to use the `getDefaultMiddleware` function to obtain the default middleware and combine it with custom middleware.

try this

```
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userAPI.middleware)
```

Comment: so what is the format if I have more than one middleware in ```configureStore```?

Comment: May I ask is it possible to use something like ```getDefaultMiddleware().concat([userAPI.middleware, productAPI.middleware])```? I'm not sure what is the correct format to combine the middlewares?

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple arguments to `.concat()` - it's the standard `Array.concat()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the actual error message is I can certainly say that your code is *not* using the correct syntax for adding additional middlewares in Typescript.

See [middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware)

> ### middleware
>
> A callback which will receive `getDefaultMiddleware` as its argument,
> and should return a middleware array.
>
> If this option is provided, it should return all the middleware
> functions you want added to the store. `configureStore` will
> automatically pass those to `applyMiddleware`.
>
> If not provided, `configureStore` will call `getDefaultMiddleware` and
> use the array of middleware functions it returns.
>
> For more details on how the `middleware` parameter works and the list
> of middleware that are added by default, see the
> [`getDefaultMiddleware` docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware).
>
> > **TUPLE**
> >
> > Typescript users are required to use a `Tuple` instance (if not using
> > a `getDefaultMiddleware` result, which is already a `Tuple`), for
> > better inference.
> >
> > ```
> > import { configureStore, Tuple } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
> >
> > configureStore({
> >   reducer: rootReducer,
> >   middleware: () => new Tuple(additionalMiddleware, logger),
> > })
> > ```
> >
> > Javascript-only users are free to use a plain array if preferred.

If just adding your own middleware return a `Tuple`.

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userAPI } from "./api/userAPI";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [userAPI.reducerPath]: userAPI.reducer,
  },
  middleware: () => new Tuple(userAPI.middleware),
});
```

If you would additionally like the default middlewares, use the `concat` and `prepend` methods from the [getDefaultMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) function.

```js
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userAPI.middleware),
```

If you had multiple middlewares to add, you still just use the same `concat` or `prepend` methods.

```js
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
   getDefaultMiddleware()
    .concat(
      analytics,
      logger,
      userAPI.middleware,
      // etc
    ),
```

Comment: The OP is using perfectly valid JavaScript. It's syntactic sugar.

Comment: @AluanHaddad For Javascript, yes, for Typescript, no, there are tighter requirements. See the linked documentation and [middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware) for typescript details. Typescript users must return a `Tuple` of their middlewares or use the `getDefaultMiddleware` function if they want them and their additional middleware(s).

Comment: You are saying that TypeScript doesn't recognize a valid JavaScript expression?

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, not at all. I'm saying that Typescript users have to follow certain patterns when using Redux-Toolkit. I'd follow the documentation and maintainers' advice/recommendations. I'll surface their recommendation better.

Comment: We've tightened up `configureStore`'s TS types to correctly infer specifics about each provided middleware, but passing a raw JS array loses that information.  So, as of RTK 2.0, _if_ you are not calling `getDefaultMiddleware()`, you _must_ use the included `Tuple` type instead to correctly retain the middleware type info: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware